# Is there a way to see the action of a shell script as it is executed?

Tags: bash

I am pretty new here and learning programming.
I wonder if there is a way to see the action of a shell script as it is executed?
For example, I want to see how the values are inserted into the variables in this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script: potenz2.sh (powers of two with a while loop)
i=0
j=1
while (( i < 12 ))
do
        j=$((j * 2))
        echo -n "$j"
        i=$((i+1))
done
echo ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, or run it with that option

```
bash -x potenz2.sh
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barmar.
I didn't know it could be so easy.
There are so many things to learn.